# Set spacing buttons

Tags: xaml, windows-10, uwp, uwp-xaml

How do I put a space between the buttons? I am using Relative Panel, and I am the first button aligns with the center of the panel, and do not want the buttons to be together as is in the Picture:

[image]

```
<RelativePanel>
            <Button Name="Button1"
                    Content="Button 1"
                    RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
                    RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True"/>
            <Button Name="Button2"
                    Content="Button 2"
                    RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
                    RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True"
                    RelativePanel.Below="Button1"/>
            <Button Name="Button3"
                    Content="Button 3"
                    RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
                    RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True"
                    RelativePanel.Below="Button2"/>
    </RelativePanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the options is to set buttons margin.
For ex:

```
<Button Name="Button1"
        Content="Button 1"
        RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
        RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True"
        Margin="5"/>
```

It means that first button will have margin equal 5 pixels from each side.